# Can the Outlook addin Javascript file get information from manifest file?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an Outlook addin and we are evaluating to see if we can pass information from manifest file to the Javascript API callback.
Ex : we need some port information to be available in the manifest and this should be passed to the Javascript API callback on ItemSend.

Is there a way for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but there is no way for JavaScript in your add-in to read its own manifest at runtime.

Comment: The information in the manifest is static, and shouldn't change. Usually when people request this they have multiple manifests for the same add-in code. (that go out to different audiences?) One workaround that people do is use a Query Parameter if they are loading an html page. (i.e. adjust the URL in the manifest to include the information you want). However, if you are using an Outlook Event Based Add-in, (LaunchEvent) this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rick mentioned, `OfficeJS` doesn't provide any straight mechanism for getting the manifest file content.

But you may consider your manifest file as any other file xml file hosted on the server, so you can read its content like any other file, of course, it is hosted on the web server somewhere (with your web application).

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's the case. The manifest is "hosted" in Office, not on the add-in's web server. The best that could be done is to host a copy of the manifest on the server.

Comment: Right, but the add-in is installed from somewhere. And if that is a web server, the add-in can read it using standard tools.

Comment: But it is not on a web server. The manifest is installed from AppSource, or Central Deployment, or a SharePoint catalog, or (on Windows only) a network share, etc. It is not on a web server in the normal way of hosting files on a web server. For example, it doesn't have a public URL on AppSource that would be knowable at coding time (if ever).

Comment: There is no typical scenario. Everybody decides how to deploy a web add-in. But to reflect your points I've updated the post. I agree if the manifest is not hosted anywhere (like in case of AppSource) there is no way trivial way to get its content.